# excel alphanumeric sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I need to generate a 4-digit alphanumeric code. It should run in the following sequence:

0000 > 0001 > 0002 > 0003 > 0004 > 0005 > 0006 > 0007 > 0008 > 0009 > 000A > 000B
...
ZZZO > ZZZP > ZZZQ > ZZZR > ZZZS > ZZZT > ZZZU > ZZZV > ZZZW > ZZZX > ZZZY > ZZZZ

I have tried breaking up the code into the four digits and then using concatenate to combine them again.

There are add-ons available that may be able to help me, but I would rather try to find a formula before opting for an add-on.

Comment: Show us the formulas you have tried. What do you want to do with this? You realize you will have more items than can fit into a single column. `1,679,616` to be precise

Comment: I also recommend avoiding using the letter "O" and the "I" as depending on font they can be hard to distinguish from the 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ron stated above, there are 36^4 = 1,679,616 values in that sequence which is too large to fit into any one row or column in excel.  Therefore, I would suggest putting the sequence into a 1,296 x 1,296 grid.

Before creating the grid, enter the unique values (0-9, A-Z) in cells A1:A36.  Then create a 2-character sequence in cell C4 and copy it down and across to cell D1299:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$36,QUOTIENT(ROW()-4,36)+1,1)
```

From here you can copy, paste and transpose the values in cells E2:AWZ3.  The last step would be to concatenate the values by this formula in Cell E4:

```
=CONCATENATE($C4,$D4,E$2,E$3)
```

Copy this formula to the range E4:AWZ1299 for a final result.  It should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Copying the "Wise" idea of putting the results into a square matrix, and making use of Dominique's pseudo-code for a VBA routine, we come up with:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Dural()
    Dim a(35) As String
    Dim I As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim vRes, V

'populate array with the individual items
For I = 0 To 9
    a(I) = CStr(I)
Next I
For I = 10 To 35
    a(I) = Chr(I + 55)
Next I

Set col = New Collection
I = 0
For j = 0 To 35
    For k = 0 To 35
        For l = 0 To 35
            For m = 0 To 35
                I = I + 1
                col.Add CStr(a(j) & a(k) & a(l) & a(m))
            Next m
        Next l
    Next k
Next j

ReDim vRes(1 To 1296, 1 To 1296)
I = 0
j = 1
For Each V In col
    I = I + 1
    If I > UBound(vRes, 1) Then
        j = j + 1
        I = 1
    End If
    vRes(I, j) = V
Next V

Dim R As Range
Set R = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(UBound(vRes, 1), 2 + UBound(vRes, 2)))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With R
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Although it seems a bit convoluted, by

- collecting the results in a collection
- populating a VBA array with the results and then
- writing the vba array to the worksheet range

the code runs much more quickly than if we were to do serial write's to the worksheet.  On my machine the routine takes just over four seconds

Answer (score 1):

In VBA (pseudo-code): make a list/collection of some sort, like this:

```
A[0] = "0"
A[1] = "1"
...
A[9] = "9"
A[10] = "A"
A[11] = "B"
...
A[35] = "Z"

For i = 0 to 35:
  For j = 0 to 35:
    For k = 0 to 35:
      For l = 0 to 35:
        println(A[i] + A[j] + A[k] + A[l]);
      Next l
    Next k
  Next j
Next i
```